# Named ranges using an index/Match function to return values

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, runtime-error, match

I am using named ranges in a worksheet due to them changing often, and am trying to use an Index/Match function on a range of values.  I have it working properly on a single cell, but I can't get it to work on a range of cells like how a Vlookup would.

I am running the VBA code from the Workbook containing the Daily sheet, which opens the Workbook containing the Teams sheet.

Here is what I have in VBA:

```
Dim Teams as worksheet
Dim Daily as worksheet
Set Teams = Sheets("Teams")
Set Daily = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Daily")

With Teams
    .Range("TeamTotals").Formula = WorksheetFunction.Index(Daily.Range("$:$H"), WorksheetFunction.Match(.Range("TeamTotals").Offset(, -7), Daily.Range("$D,$H"), 0)) 
End Teams
```

It throws a 1004 Error Method of 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Any idea how I can get this to run over a range of values?  I need to use OFFSET which is why I can't use a VLOOKUP

Comment: Noticed that I have to use Application.Match when I use a single cell, but that still doesn't work on a range, same error

Comment: You have "$:$H", which looks invalid.

Comment: ack...it is supposed to be $H:$H which is what it is in my code, I just mistyped it

Comment: You should use copy/paste to get your code into the text box when you post a question or solution. Is "$D,$H" also a typo?

Comment: Yeah, its supopsed to $D:$H...I actually got it working using an offset with VLookup, and then actually figured it out using Index/Match...I was referencing the wrong columns...